# How to prevent inline divs from jumping to the next line within a parent?

Tags: css, html

I have two inline divs which exceed in width the parent's width. Therefore the second div jumps to the next line:
http://jsfiddle.net/uVqG6/2/

How can I keep both divs on the same line?

Adding `overflow:hidden;` to div.a simply hides the second div.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute;` for this, else no other way except increasing your container div width or making it `nowrap`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uVqG6/9/)

Using `z-index` [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uVqG6/10/)

CSS

```
.a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 1px #345;
    position: relative;
}

.b {
    width: 60px;    
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.c {
    width: 50px;    
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: The absolute position solution is a hack, and your specific implementation is changing the display order of the divs.

Comment: Using `white-space: no-wrap;` didn't seem to help in my case. Absolute positioning however did the trick.

Comment: @Ramin, I updated your example specifically to work with no-wrap. Mr Alien's solution is still a hack, which will only work for 2 elements. If that's all you need, that's fine, but you'll have to learn a different solution in the future if you ever want to add an additional element. That, or keep adding css for each new element.

Answer (score 13):

Theres a couple of ways to do this. First of all, you can use `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;` to get the divs to sit side by side. They work different, so be sure to use the right one for your case.

Second, neither of those will work unless the containing div (a) is large enough to contain both of the divs on the same line. Or, you can use `overflow: hidden;` on the containing div (a).

**Edit:**

I've updated your example: http://jsfiddle.net/uVqG6/11/

I had to use `white-space: nowrap;`, since the inside divs were wrapping.

Here's another answer which also answers your question: [CSS: how to stop text from taking up more than 1 line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572298/css-how-to-stop-text-from-taking-up-more-than-1-line)

Remeber that using `display: inline-block` basically treats the element as text, so most text-formatting css properties will apply to it.

Comment: white-space: nowrap; was what I was looking for, thx

Answer (score 8):

Inline elements behave in much the same way as text does. If you want to prevent them from wrapping, either remove the white space you have used for formatting, or add `white-space:nowrap;` to the rule for `.a`.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/bfkgT/

Answer (score 7):

```
.a {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
border: solid 1px #345;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:hidden; }
```

Does this do what you want?