# How to prevent div become two rows?

Tags: css

I have a web page which has two divs in one line. However, some times they become two lines, when the content is too long to display. My css is as follow:

```
.bubble{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #B2B2B2;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow:hidden;    
}
```

And here's the html:

```
<div class="bubble"></div>
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

How can I make it always in one line? Thanks

Comment: Use width, % or constants.

Comment: You may need to try to fix the width

Comment: What is your HTML? Just your CSS is rather uninformative without your content.

Comment: -1 because you failed to supply any HTML, and you failed to describe what you want the final layout to be like.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `display: table`, `table-cell` and `table-row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `float` to cause your divs to be side-by-side, make the two divs `display:inline-block`, and make their parent container have `white-space:nowrap`. Then they will behave like two normally-inline elements, such as `<span>` or `<img>`.

Alternatively (as well-suggested by @frozenkoi) use `display:table-row` on the container and `display:table-cell` on the divs (or some other legal combination).

Answer (score 1):

`width:auto` will make the width of the div equal to the content of the divs. When the content is too long for one line, it will bump them to two lines. To make them always on one line, you can do something like `width:50%;`, `max-width:50%` or `width: somevalue` where `somevalue` is less than or equal to half the parent's width.

If you wish to have both of the divs have an adjustable width that is always a single line, you could use a smidge of JavaScript. This assumes that you have one div that is dynamic and the other that will "fill", and that you are using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parent_width = SOME_VALUE;
    var primary_width = $('.bubble.primary').width();
    var secondary_width = parent_width - primary_width;
    $('.bubble.secondary').css('width', secondary_width);
});
```

Comment: See my comment on Genocide_Hoax's answer for why `width:50%` is not useful to the OP _unless_ you change the box-sizing.

Comment: Very true. Silly box sizing model. [Here's the Paul Irish article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) explaining why elements that add up to `width:100%` plus padding will lead to line breaks, and what you need to do to prevent that.

Comment: Hi is there a pure css solution?

Comment: See Phrogz' answer - `display:inline-block` plus `white-space:nowrap` will ensure that the two elements do not break onto two lines. `overflow:hidden` will ensure that the content of the divs doesn't extend past the edge of the div. It will chop off any content that extends past the edge, however.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is not considered good practice to rely on DIV to segment markup that must be rendered in a single line. You should consider using two SPAN elements instead of two DIVs.

However if you really must, you can add CSS3 styles to your DIV to get it to 'behave like' a SPAN. Here's the CSS:

```
div.nowrap {
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You'll also need to wrap both the DIV elements in an outer DIV. This is because the CSS styles will act upon each individual DIV and its contents, and the browser will treat them independently when computing its layout. So, the markup would look like:

```
<div id='outer' class='nowrap'>
   <div id='inner1' class='nowrap'>This is a very very long line.</div>
   <div id='inner2' class='nowrap'>This is another very very long line.</div>
</div>
```

Without an outer DIV, the browser may choose to "wrap" the two inner DIV elements when computing layout by deciding that they best fit on separate lines.

Detailed explanation:

Understand that `display: inline` will tell the browser to create a text-flow-like layout for this element rather than a block.

Also note that the both `overflow: hidden` and `overflow-x: hidden` are needed to address overflow behaviour in the vertical and horizontal directions, respectively.

Finally, the appropriate word-wrap behaviour uses `white-space: nowrap`. The `word-break` attribute that you are specifying only relates to *where* a line might be wrapped and not *whether* it is wrapped.

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572298/css-how-to-stop-text-from-taking-up-more-than-1-line) (for pre-CSS3).

Comment: Note: `display:inline` is not CSS3. It is [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#display), made non-optional in CSS2.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    <style>
    #a
    {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    }
    #b
    {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    }


 #container
    {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    }
    </style>
<div id=container>
    <div id="a" >
    <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>

    <div id="b"> 
    <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that with the default `box-sizing:content-box`, using `width:50%` will produce undesirable results with the padding that the OP has already said is being used. You need to put a `box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box` for this to work well.

Comment: Well , I didn't consider the OP's CSS in this matter. Was trying to point out how we can divide two div's equally without any overflow. But Thanks for the add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Use max-width or explicitly set the size of the width using percentage, em or fixed value.

Or you can enclose the content in p or span and adjust width size there.