# Avoid line break between html elements

Tags: html, whitespace

I have this `<td>` element:

```
<td><i class="flag-bfh-ES"></i>&nbsp;+34&nbsp;666&nbsp;66&nbsp;66&nbsp;66</td>
```

I was hoping to keep this into a single line, but this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, flag and telephone number are in separate lines. The `&nbsp;` are working in between the numbers of the telephone number, but not between flag and telephone number.

How can I make sure that no line-break at all is introduced by the renderer?

Comment: Voting to reopen, since this is about elements, not text as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572298/how-to-stop-text-from-taking-up-more-than-1-line

Answer (score 211, accepted):

There are several ways to prevent line breaks in content. Using `&nbsp;` is one way, and works fine between words, but using it between an empty element and some text does not have a well-defined effect. The same would apply to the more logical and more accessible approach where you use an image for an icon.

The most robust alternative is to use `nobr` markup, which is nonstandard but universally supported and works even when CSS is disabled:

```
<td><nobr><i class="flag-bfh-ES"></i> +34 666 66 66 66</nobr></td>
```

(You can, but need not, use `&nbsp;` instead of spaces in this case.)

Another way is the `nowrap` attribute (deprecated/obsolete, but still working fine, except for some rare quirks):

```
<td nowrap><i class="flag-bfh-ES"></i> +34 666 66 66 66</td>
```

Then there’s the CSS way, which works in CSS enabled browsers and needs a bit more code:

```
<style>
.nobr { white-space: nowrap }
</style>
...
<td class=nobr><i class="flag-bfh-ES"></i> +34 666 66 66 66</td>
```

Comment: Re: nobr, mozilla warns "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future." -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr

Comment: @Luke, that’s a “standard” warning. They don’t describe any incompatibility (even a small one) and don’t mention any browser that does not support `nobr`; there are none.

Comment: The `nobr` tag is in the same category as using `blink`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete Either you work towards web standards or you work towards a chaotic web. The choice is yours.

Comment: @Luke, `nobr` has universal browser support, `blink` always had limited support and has now lost all, so if you put them into the same category... Re “standards”, note that you cite a document that says: “This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress.”

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, a class "text-nowrap" is already defined which sets the stype accordingly.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, HTML5 is now finalized and, very unsurprisingly, `nobr` is still deprecated and _"must not be used"_.

Comment: Haters may hate, but I think this is beautiful Jukka. You are invited to my Birthday party if you want to come

Comment: april 2022 & `nobr` still works

Answer (score 89):

CSS for that td: `white-space: nowrap;` should solve it.

Answer (score 14):

If you need this for several words or elements, but can't apply it to a whole TD or similar, the Span tag can be used.

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap">Text to break together</span>
    or 
<span class=nobr>Text to break together</span>
```

If you use the class version, remember to set up the CSS as detailed in the accepted answer.

Comment: I like the white-space property, didnt know about it

Answer (score 4):

In some cases (e.g. html generated and inserted by JavaScript) you also may want to try to insert a zero width joiner:

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 290px;   
  white-space: no-wrap;
  resize:both;
  overflow:auto; 
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.breakable-text{
  display: inline;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}

.no-break-before {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="breakable-text">Lorem dorem tralalalala LAST_WORDS</span>&#8205;<span class="no-break-before">TOGETHER</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `<i>` tag isn't displayed as a block and causing the probelm then this should work:

`<td style="white-space:nowrap;"><i class="flag-bfh-ES"></i>&nbsp;+34&nbsp;666&nbsp;66&nbsp;66&nbsp;66</td>`

Answer (score 1):

This is the real solution:

```
<td>
  <span class="inline-flag">
    <i class="flag-bfh-ES"></i> 
    <span>+34 666 66 66 66</span>
  </span>
</td>
```

css:

```
.inline-flag {
   position: relative;
   display: inline;
   line-height: 14px; /* play with this */
}

.inline-flag > i {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   top: -1px; /* play with this */
}

.inline-flag > span {
   margin-left: 18px; /* play with this */
}
```

Example, images which always before text:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

nobr is too unreliable, use tables

```
<table>
      <tr>
          <td> something </td>
          <td> something </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

It all goes on the same line, everything is level with eachother, and you have much more freedom if you want to change something later.