# Prevent break between HTML tags while allowing break inside one of them

Tags: html, css

In an example like this, I want to allow wrapping within the span, but prevent breaking between the span and the i (imagine it's an icon or something with a tooltip). [Commonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512695/how-do-i-prevent-line-breaks-between-a-radio-button-and-its-label-while-still-a) it is [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212188/avoid-line-break-between-html-elements) that applying `white-space: nowrap` on the outer element and `white-space: normal` on the inner element will solve this problem, but in my testing, it does not. I've even tried putting a `&nbsp;` between the closing `span` and the opening `i`, and even that doesn't work reliably (although I believe it does work outside of codepen; I think it's doing some formatting beyond my control).

```
<div class="outer nowrap">
  <span class="allow-wrap">
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
  </span> <i>!</i>
</div>
```

See examples: https://codepen.io/bussemac/pen/WjJrba

I would prefer not having to use a `&nbsp;` if possible, because it feels fragile and something that other developers on the team might easily forget. The wrapping element is not a problem; any scenario in which we would use this, we have such an element.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.outer {  
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.no-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    1. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy <span class="no-wrap">dog <i>!</i></span>
</div>
```

Put the last word and the exclamation mark together in a span and give it a display of inline-block. This will ensure it stays with "dog ".

Comment: Difficult to do in our case; the span and the icon are both data-bound elements with localization (translations) applied. I'd have to do something like break up the first string into an "all-but-last-word" segment and the last word, which would make maintenance a nightmare, but I'll consider it if I can't find a better answer.

Comment: I did test this with a similar idea though: `...lazy dog<span class="nowrap inline-block"> <i>!</i></span>` works, if I can figure out a clean way to get the icon inside the the data-bound span without putting a bunch of HTML markup in the translation files.

Comment: This modification of your answer actually seems like it might work. https://codepen.io/bussemac/pen/jmxMWX ; I'm going to do some more testing on this, but I'll come back and mark this as the answer if it does.

Comment: It's close, but I can't any space between the last word and the icon. HTML spaces are ignored, and oddly adding any padding to the icon or its nowrap span will cause it to wrap. Even trying to use a psuedoelement to add a non-breakingspace will cause a break.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the icon in the CSS as a pseudoelement?

```css
.outer {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

span::after {
  content: "!";
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer nowrap">
  <span class="allow-wrap">
    1. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
  </span>
</div>
<br />
<div class="outer nowrap">
  <span class="allow-wrap">
    2. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
  </span>
</div>
<br />
<div class="outer nowrap">
  <span class="allow-wrap">
    3. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
  </span>
</div>
<br />
<div class="outer nowrap">
  <span class="allow-wrap">
    4. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
  </span>
</div>
```

Or retaining the current markup, use `position: absolute` on the icon..

```css
.outer {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer nowrap">
  <span class="allow-wrap">
    1. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
  </span> <i>!</i>
</div>
<br />
<div class="outer nowrap">
  <span class="allow-wrap">
    2. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
  </span><i>!</i>
</div>
<br />
<div class="outer nowrap">
  <span class="allow-wrap">
    3. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
  </span><i class="inline-block">!</i>
</div>
<br />
<div class="outer nowrap">
  <span class="allow-wrap">
    4. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
  </span><i class="inline-block">!</i>
</div>
```

Comment: _"imagine it's an icon or something with a tooltip"_ -  How would you implement a tooltip with this scenario?