# detect natural line breaks javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

When I type in a non-resizeable text area something like `hello world, this is a demo` and the text area is small enough, it will look like this:

```
hello world,
this is a demo
```

This is not caused by a \n or something.
How can I detect this natural line break in a text area?
A fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/yx6B7/
As you can see, there is a line break, but javascript just says that it's one big line without any line-breaks in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding "line-breaks" in textarea that is word-wrapping ARABIC text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719777/finding-line-breaks-in-textarea-that-is-word-wrapping-arabic-text)

Comment: detect and then...? What's the ultimate goal?

Comment: @thg435: To convert those line-breaks to real breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this script on the internet:

```
function ApplyLineBreaks(strTextAreaId) {
var oTextarea = document.getElementById(strTextAreaId);
if (oTextarea.wrap) {
    oTextarea.setAttribute("wrap", "off");
}
else {
    oTextarea.setAttribute("wrap", "off");
    var newArea = oTextarea.cloneNode(true);
    newArea.value = oTextarea.value;
    oTextarea.parentNode.replaceChild(newArea, oTextarea);
    oTextarea = newArea;
}

var strRawValue = oTextarea.value;
oTextarea.value = "";
var nEmptyWidth = oTextarea.scrollWidth;
var nLastWrappingIndex = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < strRawValue.length; i++) {
    var curChar = strRawValue.charAt(i);
    if (curChar == ' ' || curChar == '-' || curChar == '+')
        nLastWrappingIndex = i;
    oTextarea.value += curChar;
    if (oTextarea.scrollWidth > nEmptyWidth) {
        var buffer = "";
        if (nLastWrappingIndex >= 0) {
            for (var j = nLastWrappingIndex + 1; j < i; j++)
                buffer += strRawValue.charAt(j);
            nLastWrappingIndex = -1;
        }
        buffer += curChar;
        oTextarea.value = oTextarea.value.substr(0, oTextarea.value.length - buffer.length);
        oTextarea.value += "\n" + buffer;
    }
}
oTextarea.setAttribute("wrap", "");
document.getElementById("pnlPreview").innerHTML = oTextarea.value.replace(new RegExp("\\n", "g"), "<br />");
```

}

Which is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a javascript problem.

Look at the `word-wrap`, `white-space` and `overflow` css properties.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572298/css-how-to-stop-text-from-taking-up-more-than-1-line