# Stop text from wrapping to 3 or more lines

Tags: css

Is there some way to stop text from wrapping over more than 2 lines.  If the text is short it will appear on 1 line.  Longer text then goes onto the second line but I want to stop there and put ellipses at the end and not have the text go onto the 3rd or further lines.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572298/css-how-to-stop-text-from-taking-up-more-than-1-line) post but it deals with stopping the wrapping after the first line.

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k5VET/

Comment: check this for pur css solution http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai these are great suggestions.  I'm wondering why you haven't posted these are answers.

Comment: Kanith if you got the right solution then it is fine. Also those are all i got when i checked in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pvbmafaL/1/)**

You can limit the maximum height of element and put `overflow: hidden;` to keep it max 2 lines.

keep your values in em so that this solution works for any font size.

**Code:**

```
p{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    max-height: 3.2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This does not put any ellipses anywhere, so it does not do what the question asks for. It may be a good answer to some other question.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify div height, with overflow hidden css property.
It will not show the 3rd line.

If you want to put ellipses, you will need to use javascriot/JQuery solution, to limit the length of the string.